# Count if matched 2 criteria Google Sheets

Tags: spreadsheet, countif

I have question about how to count if matched 2 criteria
This is my sample file : [SAMPLE FILE COUNTIF](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DwKLp6w2UcFR7DYwJ0QgkvHc65PXHU9rFMa3fL5k5O8/edit#gid=0)

I also put my expectation result in my file, maybe you'll easily understand after open my file.

Thank You!

Comment: Can you explain how you determine the expected result?

Comment: hi mike, I got the formula already...thank you